# GitLab CI : My Test Job doesn't pickup the mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a springboot application that is connected to a mysql database. I want to use the .gitlab-ci.yml to handle the pipeline. I created the following config file.

```
before_script:
 - echo "Execute scripts which are required to bootstrap the application. !"

after_script:
 - echo "Clean up activity can be done here !."

services:
 - mysql

stages:
 - build
 - connect
 - test
 - package
 - deploy

variables:
 MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"
 MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
 MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME: gyyconsortiumdb
 MYSQL_DATABASE_SCHEMA: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/src/main/resources/static/sql/gyyconsortiumdb.sql"
 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql

cache:
 paths:
  - .m2/repository/
  - target/

build:
 stage: build
 image: maven:latest
 script:
  - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean compile

connect:
 stage: connect
 image: mysql
 before_script:
  - mysql --version
 script:
  - echo "create database $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME;" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql
  - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME < $MYSQL_DATABASE_SCHEMA
  - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql -e "show databases; use $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME; show tables;"

test:
 stage: test
 image: maven:latest
 script:
  - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test

package:
 stage: package
 image: maven:latest
 script:
  - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package
 artifacts:
  paths: [target/basecamp-0.0.1.war]


deploy_test:
 stage: deploy
 script:
 - echo "########   To be defined   ########"
 environment: staging

deploy_prod:
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - echo "########   To be defined   ########"
 only:
  - master
 environment: production
```

When the first job is running, it is pulling the mysql image from docker hub, and I don't know why? I thought the mysql should be built only on the connect job.

Also, after the connect job is success, the test job pull the mysql image again. And my test job doesn't recognize my database however the service was create successfully and I was able to see the database also created.

Build job console output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.3.0 (5cf5e19a)
  on docker-auto-scale (fa6cab46)
Using Docker executor with image maven:latest ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
Using docker image mysql:latest ID=sha256:7d83a47ab2d2d0f803aa230fdac1c4e53d251bfafe9b7265a3777bcc95163755 for mysql service...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Using docker image sha256:d6e999707ab00f954f4ab77c8ced4efce186099fb8318e1a0bc2f4fd8bb7bf6b for predefined container...
Pulling docker image maven:latest ...
Using docker image maven:latest ID=sha256:1f858e89a5843b0804a9e1498476a135f45e23a42fe673914f977e0882a6789e for build container...
Running on runner-fa6cab46-project-4899225-concurrent-0 via runner-fa6cab46-srm-1514081729-3d654341...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/user/xxx'...
Checking out b9efb2da as 24-create-the-gitlab-ci-yml-file...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Downloading cache.zip from http://runners-cache-3-internal.gitlab.com:444/runner/project/4899225/default 
Successfully extracted cache
$ echo "Execute scripts which are required to bootstrap the application. !"
Execute scripts which are required to bootstrap the application. !
$ mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxx 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Deleting /builds/user/xxx/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 108 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 35 source files to /builds/user/xxx/target/classes
[WARNING] /builds/user/xxx/src/main/java/com//www/xxx/domain/Project.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /builds/user/xxx/src/main/java/com/xxx/www/xxx/domain/Project.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.111 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-24T02:18:07Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/71M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Running after script...
$ echo "Clean up activity can be done here !."
Clean up activity can be done here !.
Creating cache default...
.m2/repository/: found 1775 matching files         
target/: found 197 matching files                  
Uploading cache.zip to http://runners-cache-3-
internal.gitlab.com:444/runner/project/4899225/default 
Created cache
Job succeeded
```

Connect job console output

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.3.0 (5cf5e19a)
  on docker-auto-scale (e11ae361)
Using Docker executor with image mysql ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
Using docker image mysql:latest ID=sha256:7d83a47ab2d2d0f803aa230fdac1c4e53d251bfafe9b7265a3777bcc95163755 for mysql service...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Using docker image sha256:295a9e80fe6ae475bfeef8e318eb11db267d317fa6bc1ed8d72185dfd2adb8b7 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image mysql ...
Using docker image mysql ID=sha256:7d83a47ab2d2d0f803aa230fdac1c4e53d251bfafe9b7265a3777bcc95163755 for build container...
Running on runner-e11ae361-project-4899225-concurrent-0 via runner-e11ae361-srm-1514081811-5092ac06...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/yimengael/basecamp'...
Checking out b9efb2da as 24-create-the-gitlab-ci-yml-file...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Downloading cache.zip from http://runners-cache-5-internal.gitlab.com:444/runner/project/4899225/default 
Successfully extracted cache
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
$ echo "create database $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME;" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
$ mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME < $MYSQL_DATABASE_SCHEMA
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
$ mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql -e "show databases; use $MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME; show tables;"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Database
information_schema
mydb
mysql
performance_schema
sys
Tables_in_mydb
message
persistent_logins
project
project_description
role
user
user_role
Running after script...
$ echo "Clean up activity can be done here !."
Clean up activity can be done here !.
Creating cache default...
.m2/repository/: found 1775 matching files         
target/: found 197 matching files                  
Archive is up to date!                             
Created cache
Job succeeded
```

Test job failed :

```
2017-12-24 02:21:43.827  INFO 62 --- [           main] c.g.w.b.xxxWebApplicationTests      : Starting xxxWebApplicationTests on runner-4e4528ca-project-4899225-concurrent-0 with PID 62 (started by root in /builds/yimengael/xxx)
2017-12-24 02:21:43.829 DEBUG 62 --- [           main] c.g.w.b.xxxWebApplicationTests      : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.8.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.12.RELEASE
2017-12-24 02:21:43.829  INFO 62 --- [           main] c.g.w.b.xxxWebApplicationTests      : The following profiles are active: dev
2017-12-24 02:21:45.101  INFO 62 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@62e20a76: startup date [Sun Dec 24 02:21:45 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-24 02:21:49.515  INFO 62 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-12-24 02:21:51.533  WARN 62 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 50
2017-12-24 02:21:52.448 ERROR 62 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mydb'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

.....

2017-12-24 02:21:52.477  WARN 62 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mydb'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:339)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139)
```

Could you please tell me why the test job does not pick up the mysql service the right way ?

Best,
G

Answer (score 0):

> When the first job is running, it is pulling the mysql image from
>   docker hub, and I don't know why?

Because you defined Mysql as a service. GitLab CI uses the services keyword to define what docker containers should be linked with your base image. So, it will be run for every stages.

> Could you please tell me why the test job does not pick up the mysql
>   service the right way ?

Your database name in your gitlab config file is 'gyyconsortiumdb' which is different from what you defined in your spring config file as log shows you are trying to connect to 'mydb'

jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mydb'

follow the link for more info
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/services/mysql.html

Comment: Thanks Javad, For your comments. That was helpful. The other issue that I have now is to implement the deploy jobs for test and production. In fact, I want to use the Docker cloud to deploy my app in test and production environment. Here is the description of my architecture : for test environment , I want to use a load balancer, behind this lb two container for Tomcat and one container for the Database. I don’t have a lot of experience in Docker and Docker cloud. Can you please explain me the process step by step so that I can deploy my app in Docker cloud ?